# Windows 11 Settings app will no longer opening

Tags: windows, windows-11

When I try to open the app I get the following message:

> We’re updating Settings. It should be ready to use again shortly.

[image]

When I run:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

I get this output:

```
Name                   : windows.immersivecontrolpanel
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : Neutral
ResourceId             : neutral
Version                : 10.0.8.1000
PackageFullName        : windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.8.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
InstallLocation        : C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy
PublisherId            : cw5n1h2txyewy
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-144685632-2172771273-2963176446-1001
                         [S-1-5-21-144685632-2172771273-2963176446-1001]: Installed,
                         S-1-5-21-144685632-2172771273-2963176446-500 [S-1-5-21-144685632-2172771273-2963176446-500]:
                         Installed, S-1-5-21-144685632-2172771273-2963176446-1000
                         [S-1-5-21-144685632-2172771273-2963176446-1000]: Installed, S-1-5-18 [S-1-5-18]: Installed...}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : True
Dependencies           : {Microsoft.UI.Xaml.CBS_9.2311.10002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : System
Status                 : DeploymentInProgress, Servicing
```

The relevant part being the last line:

```
Status                 : DeploymentInProgress, Servicing
```

This has been going on for weeks during which I've installed several Windows updates and restarted several times.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try the various solutions in [this article](https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-settings-app-not-working-in-windows-11).

Comment: My suggestion is perform **Reset-AppxPackage -Package windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy** as an Administrator

Answer (score 0):

> This has been going on for weeks during which I've installed several
> Windows updates and restarted several times.

Given the updates and length of time, I suuggest it is now time to try a Windows 11 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

> Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB
> key as running the download creates a USB Key.
>
> Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
>
> Proceed normally answering the prompts.
>
> The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

A Repair Install often fixes issues like this.

If not, then there is more serious damage and / or a Windows User Profile error.

In either case, for the latter, back everything up, install Windows 11 fresh and recover backed up documents and email.